# Javascript global variable resetting on function call from php

Tags: javascript

I'm building a website with php and js, and I've run into a problem where my global variable resets to 0 when my js function is called from a button click in php.

My code:

```js
var i = 0;

function increment() {
  i += 1;
}

function decrement() {
  i -= 1;
}

for (var x=0; x<10; x++) {
  var field = document.getElementById("field"+x);
  var input = document.getElementById("f"+x);
  if (input.value !== "") {
    field.removeAttribute("style");
    increment();
  }
}
decrement();

console.log("INITIAL: "+i);

function addfieldFunction() {
  console.log(i);
  if(i<9){
    increment();
  }
  var field = document.getElementById("field"+i);
  if (field !== null) {
    field.removeAttribute("style");
  }
  
}

function deletefieldFunction() {
  var field = document.getElementById("field"+i);
  var input = document.getElementById("f"+i);
  if (field !== null) {
    field.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
    input.setAttribute("value", "");
    decrement();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="form-div" class="w3-left w3-container" style="padding:0px; width:100%">
          <div id="field0">
              <label class="w3-left">Field 1</label> <br>
              <input id="f0" style="width:100%" name="field0" type="text" value="1" size="100%">
          </div>
          <div id="field1" style="display: none;">
              <label class="w3-left">Field 2</label> <br>
              <input id="f1" style="width:100%" name="field1" type="text" value="2" size="100%">
          </div>
          <div id="field2" style="display: none;">
              <label class="w3-left">Field 3</label> <br>
              <input id="f2" style="width:100%" name="field2" type="text" value="3" size="100%">
          </div>
          <div id="field3" style="display: none;">
              <label class="w3-left">Field 4</label> <br>
              <input id="f3" style="width:100%" name="field3" type="text" value="4" size="100%">
          </div>
          <div id="field4" style="display: none;">
              <label class="w3-left">Field 5</label> <br>
              <input id="f4" style="width:100%" name="field4" type="text" value="" size="100%">
          </div>
          <div id="field5" style="display: none;">
              <label class="w3-left">Field 6</label> <br>
              <input id="f5" style="width:100%" name="field5" type="text" value="" size="100%">
          </div>
          <div id="field6" style="display: none;">
              <label class="w3-left">Field 7</label> <br>
              <input id="f6" style="width:100%" name="field6" type="text" value="" size="100%">
          </div>
          <div id="field7" style="display: none;">
              <label class="w3-left">Field 8</label> <br>
              <input id="f7" style="width:100%" name="field7" type="text" value="" size="100%">
          </div>
          <div id="field8" style="display: none;">
              <label class="w3-left">Field 9</label> <br>
              <input id="f8" style="width:100%" name="field8" type="text" value="" size="100%">
          </div>
          <div id="field9" style="display: none;">
              <label class="w3-left">Field 10</label> <br>
              <input id="f9" style="width:100%" name="field9" type="text" value="" size="100%">
          </div>
          
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
          <button type="button" class="w3-button" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-size: 20px;" onclick="addfieldFunction()">ADD</button>
          <button type="button" class="w3-button" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-size: 20px;" onclick="deletefieldFunction()">DELETE</button>
        </div>
```

When the page loads, console.log(i) displays the correct i value I am looking for. However...

```
<div id="buttons">
  <button type="button" class="w3-button" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-size: 20px;" onclick="addfieldFunction()">ADD</button>
  <button type="button" class="w3-button" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; font-size: 20px;" onclick="deletefieldFunction()">DELETE</button>
</div>
```

pressing either of these buttons resets my global variable i to 0, then increments/decrements them.

Why is this the case? When the page loads, the i value should be set to the value determined in the for loop, but it doesn't persist to the functions.

EDIT: For some reason, the code works in the snippet, but not on my actual website. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know the value of `i` resets to `0`? You only have the one `console.log(i)`. Could you please convert your code to a runnable Stack Snippet, including examples of these fields?

Comment: @Phil I added the code snippet, and it's working as expected here, but not on my website!!

Comment: Do you have a `<form>` tag in your website html (with empty action)? If yes, it could be that clicking the button is submitting the form and reloading the page.

Comment: @Alisson I do have a <form> tag which submits the contents of the fields to mySQL database. However, since the add/delete button are type="button", they don't submit the form!

Comment: @Anonymous as far as I know if the function called by the button throws an exception, the button will submit the form (regardless of its type) unless you explicitly call `e.preventDefault()` before the exception OR change it to return false: `onclick="addfieldFunction(); return false;"`.